# How can I solve this recurrent equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

```
f[1]  = 5
f[2]  = f[1]  + 3*0
f[3]  = f[2]  + 3*0
f[4]  = f[3]  + 3*0
f[5]  = f[4]  + 3*1
f[6]  = f[5]  + 3*1
f[7]  = f[6]  + 3*1
f[8]  = f[7]  + 3*1
f[9]  = f[8]  + 3*2
f[10] = f[9]  + 3*2
f[11] = f[10] + 3*2
f[12] = f[11] + 3*2
f[13] = f[12] + 3*3
f[14] = f[13] + 3*3
f[15] = f[14] + 3*3
f[16] = f[15] + 3*3
f[17] = f[16] + 3*4
f[18] = f[17] + 3*4
f[19] = f[18] + 3*4
f[20] = f[19] + 3*4
…
f[n] = f[n-1] + 3*...


For $n=1,2,3, \ldots$
```

The solution should only depend on $n$

```
f[n] = ?
```

These are the first $50$ numbers

```
5     5     5     5     8    11    14    17    23    29    35    41    50    59    68    77    89   101   113   125   140   155   170   185   203   221   239   257   278   299   320   341   365   389   413   437   464   491   518   545   575   605   635   665   698   731   764   797   833   869
```

EDIT: In case it is useful, I made this algorithm in octave/matlab to generate the sequence.

```
a = zeros(120,1);
a(1) = 5;
a(2) = 5;
a(3) = 5;
a(4) = 5;
inc = 3;
for i = 1:29
    for j = 1:4
        a(i*4+j) = a(i*4+j-1) + inc;
    end
    inc = inc + 3;
end
```

Comment: Your code explains why you think John Wayland Bales answer is wrong at $n=81$. Your code calculate only up to $n=80$.

Comment: You asked for a non-recurrent solution. May I ask why did you accept an answer with a recurrent solution instead of mine, which gives an explicit formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to break the problem down into two steps.

Notice that each number in the sequence is two more than a multiple of $3$.

So take a new sequence $g(n)$ defined as

$$ g(n)=\frac{f(n)-2}{3} $$

so that $f(n)=2+3g(n)$.

Looking at $g(n)$ we see that

1. $g(1)=g(2)=g(3)=g(4)=1$
2. $g(n)=n-4+g(n-4)$ for $n>4$

Then you may concentrate your effort in finding a general formula for $g(n)$ from which to arrive at a formula for $f(n)$

Comment: Quite close, but failed for n = 81. I am testing algorithmically. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @milla This doesn't fail for $n=81$. Check your own calculations.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake. The answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence is $f(n+1)= f(n)+3\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor$ with initial condition $f(1)=5$, which leads to $$f(n) = 5+3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\frac{k}{4}\right\rfloor$$

After some simplification considering various cases we get

$$f(n) = 5+3\left\lceil\frac{n(n-4)}{8}\right\rceil$$

Comment: Excellent. OP should select this answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_{n+1} = f_{n} + 3 \lfloor n/4\rfloor$$
where $f_1 = 5$. If you are not familiar with the $\lfloor x\rfloor$ notation, search for the floor function.

$$f_{i+1} - f_{i} = 3 \lfloor n/4\rfloor$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(f_{i+1} -f_i) = f_{n+1}- f_1 = 3\sum_{i=1}^n\lfloor i/4\rfloor$$

Since $f_1 = 5$, we get:
$$f_{n+1} = 5 + 3\sum_{i=1}^n\lfloor i/4\rfloor$$

Good chance you can get a simpler form on the sum. I will leave that to you.

Comment: ok, but it is still recurrent. I would like the non-recurrent solution.